# IBM DataStage, for Date Column, all rows failed to inserted after 0 replace it with a Default value

Tags: date, datastage

The issue is that I tried to insert data to table on oracle database. For Date column, if the Date is 0, DataStage will automatically replace it with a Default value without showing any error message, however, the rows after that 0 value actually did NOT insert to table successfully, but DataStage report all data has been inserted successfully . i.e DataStage reports that 525,000 or more rows have been inserted, But on 224000 has been inserted.

Comment: Is your date column part of the key? Are you running an Insert then Update or only Insert into that table? In general I would recommend to handle date = 0 explicitly and not trusting some default behaviour others might not be aware of.

Comment: The tables to create the Table SVC_LOC are all from oracle database, In those tables, there are Dates with zeros and real number Dates. oracle database uses Numbers for Dates.
When I try to write to the SVC_LOC table, which  dates are converted by Oracle from numbers to dates; By Oracle.
One of these default date are 01010101 and returns the date as follows  01-JAN-01; Also notice that when the dates are not 0 , oracle uses the actual number for the date using the same OCIexecuter. 
No abort and the job completes OK. However, Rows of data are missing

Comment: Thank you for your reply. let me add these additional info to a new post since stackoverflow does not allow me to edit the original post, I will provide you a link for the new post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58543957/on-datastage-datatype-date-with-zeros-and-default-values-on-oracle-table-are-mi