# on datastage, Datatype Date with zeros and default values on oracle table are missing

Tags: oracle, datastage

The tables to create the Table T_D_SVC_LOC are all from oracle database, In several of those tables, there are Dates with zeros and real number Dates. oracle database uses Numbers for Dates.
When I try to write to the T_D_PR_SVC_LOC table, which  dates are converted by Oracle from numbers to dates; By Oracle.
One of these default date are 01010101 and returns the date as follows  01-JAN-01; Also notice that when the dates are not 0 , oracle uses the actual number for the date using the same OCIexecuter. 
No abort and the job completes OK. However, Rows of data are missing or dropped for some reason.

Comment: Please show us your table definition,preferably the create table statement. Oracle stores dates internally as a number, but you should never see that. The number 0 would be translated as the lowest possible Oracle date. to convert strings to dates use the to_date function: to_date('2019-10-24 05:15', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'). The function is very flexible, it supports numerous formats. Similarly when you are converting a date to a string, use to_char as in to_char(sysdate, 'mm/dd/yy HH:MI:SS AM'); The format you are seeing is the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT for your database.

Comment: it is working fine now. Thank you very much for your comments.